# PHP echo duplicate rows when none exist

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
       $username ="matt";
       $pass = "bs12kfj";
       $db = "mytest";
       $tbl = "test2";
       mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$pass);
       mysql_select_db($db) or die( "Unable to select database");
       $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test2;");
       $num = mysql_numrows($res);
       echo "<table border='2'><tr>The Peeps</tr>"; 
       while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
         echo "<tr>";
         foreach($r as $rs){
                     echo "<td>$rs</td>";
                     }
         echo "</tr>";
       }
       ?>

</body>
```

This code executes without error but the output contains a duplicate of every column of every row like so.

`<table border='2'><tr>The Peeps</tr>

<tr><td>"matt"</td><td>"matt"</td><td>"phillips"</td><td>"phillips></td><td>"mathew.p@waburg.com"</td><td>"mathew.p@waburg.com"</td><td>20</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>"paul"</td><td>"paul"</td><td>"franklin"</td><td>"franklin"</td><td>"dude@live.com"</td><td>"dude@live.com"</td><td>30</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>"steve"</td><td>"steve"</td><td>"jobs"</td><td>"jobs"</td><td>"sjobs@apple.com"</td><td>"sjobs@apple.com"</td><td>23</td><td>23</td>`

I don't understand why each column is duplicated when there is only a single `<td></td>` tag in the echo statement.
I also checked the db and the table does not contain duplicate entries.

Comment: swap out mysql_fetch_array and replace with mysql_fetch_assoc (mysql_fetch_array returns both numeric AND associative if you don't specify otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably fetching your MySQL result array in the default mode of `MYSQL_BOTH`.

Try this:

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
             echo "<tr>";
     foreach($r as $rs){
                 echo "<td>$rs</td>";
                 }
             echo "</tr>";
       }
```

If you don't specify the second argument to `mysql_fetch_array()`, then `MYSQL_BOTH` is used, and you end up with both an associative array index of values, and a numeric array index, like this:

```
array(0 => 'field 1 val', 'field1_name'=> 'field 1 val',
      1 => 'field 2 val', 'field2_name'=> 'field 2 val', etc);
```

Specifying either `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_NUM` will only retrieve either the associative values or the numerically indexed values respectively.

Answer (score 6):

This is what [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) does if you don't provide a second argument: gets you an associative array where the value is mapped to both the column name and the column index.

You can provide `MYSQL_ASSOC`as a second argument to have only the column name (or use `mysql_fetch_assoc`).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
```

to

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
```

or

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

The default value for the 2nd argument to [`mysql_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) is `MYSQL_BOTH` which gives you back an array indexed numerically *and* associatively. Alternatively, you could use [`mysql_fetch_row()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) (returns a numerically indexed array) or [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) (returns an associative array) instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Comment: MYSQL_NUM will work with the code that controlfreak123 has, but it generally is a bad approach, because you should never assume the select fields come out of the database in the same order. The ordering can change, if you change your CREATE TABLE a bit, or when you use SELECT field1, field2 instead of *

Comment: @Anti Veeranna: How is `MYSQL_NUM` any different than `MYSQL_ASSOC` if you iterate over the results using `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

If your SQL query is

```
SELECT foo FROM bar
```

then mysql_fetch_array returns 2 results. One with numeric index, one with the field name. Add a print_r($r) into your code to see the behaviour.

Solution? [Use mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)